# How can I invert a criterion in a collection?

Tags: plone

Honestly I don't know how this could be done (if it's possible). 
I'm not seeking for a development solution, i'm seeking for a solution with a plone ootb (or a plugin).

For ex. is it possible to add a criterion that excludes all contents with a specific word in the title field from results?

or is it possible to add a path criterion that excludes all content in a specific path from results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `NOT` queries is not supported by ZCatalog OOTB but it can be done with [`AdvancedQuery`](http://www.dieter.handshake.de/pyprojects/zope/AdvancedQuery.html).  There are not add-ons that I know of that incorporate this functionality into collections for you.  IOW, this would be a development task.

Comment: I've always considered this to be a missing feature in Collections, FWIW.  Maybe we should think about PLIPing AdvancedQuery into the core so we can have more powerful Collection queries OOTB.

Comment: I'd be in favor of this, but probably not in the form of introducing yet another dependency and layer into the stack, but rather in the form of integrating the functionality into `Products.ZCatalog`.